# Core Data fetch latest object for value

Tags: ios, objective-c

i need to fetch only the latest entry for a value in the Core Data Model

Table Structure:
timestamp, receiver, message

Entry 1: 01.01.2014, 123, hello

Entry 2: 02.01.2014, 321, hello

Entry 3: 01.02.2014, 123, hello1

Entry 4; 02.02.2014, 321, hello1

I need to get only the latest entry for receiver 123 and for receiver 321.
do you have any ideas or should i change to sqlite?

thanks for ur reply

Comment: Read up on NSPredicates. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specifying that you want entries coming from receiver 123 or receiver 321, you need to make use of `NSPredicate`.

Next, for latest entry, this can be little tricky. Assuming, that for one date entry, you can make only one entry, you can rely on fact that last date entry corresponds to your latest record. But if there is chance for multiple entries corresponding to one date, then I suggest you to create one extra column saying as serial No. The reason for that is Core Data doesn't fetch your data in the order in which it was inserted. Also, it is a good practice to keep some primary key in your table which is not part of your data. Now, to fetch the smallest/largest entry, you have to make use of `NSSortDescriptor`.

I am enclosing a sample code.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"myEntityName"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"receiver == %d", receiverValue];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"serialNo" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
if ([results count] > 0) {
    MyManagedObject *object = [results firstObject];
}
```

Hope this answer helps you.